# google cloud "bucket.upload()" function is not working at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

```
async function uploadFile(filePath,destFileName) {
    const options = {
      destination: destFileName,
    };
    console.log("uploading file...");
    try{
      await bucket.upload(filePath, options);
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log("upload successful");
  };
```

The bucket.upload() function does not seem to work at all. It does not give any errors or messages and it doesn't even upload the file in the cloud as well.

The statement "uploading file is being logged in the console. But the statement "upload successful" is not logged, so I think the error should be in the bucket.upload() function. I have already checked the **filePath** and **destFilePath** and both of them are correct. I have also checked the bucket configuration and authorization, everything is fine.

The bucket.upload works perfectly fine outside the **uploadFile()** function and the uploadFile() is called with async keyword inside another function.(I don't know if this is relevant to my problem but)

Edit:-
uploadFile is called inside this function (uploadFolder), which uploads all the required files inside a folder.

```
async function uploadFolder(folderPath, destFileName){
    const files = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(folderPath, (err, files) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(files);
          }
        });
      });
      for (const file of files) {
        if (path.extname(file) === ".bson") {
          const filePath = `${folderPath}/${file}`;
          destFileName = `${destFileName}/${path.basename(file)}`;
          await uploadFile(filePath, destFileName);
        }
      }
};
```

UploadFolder is called inside backup function which scheduled with cron to run everyday. Here is the backup function if you need it:-

```
async function backup(element){
    // code defining variables like backupPath, folderPath etc.
    
    await localDump(element, backupPath);
    //local dump function works completely fine.
    await uploadFolder(folderPath, destFileName);
}
```

Comment: You should edit the  question show the entire program, not just a function. If you're saying upload works, but just not with this function, then maybe it matters how you are calling this function.

Comment: The complete code is a bit long but I have updated the code as you told.

Comment: Ideally, the code you provide is complete so that we can copy it and run it for ourselves so that we can observe the same behavior.